# Yii2 ActiveRecord->save() returns true, no data inserted in database

Tags: php, activerecord, yii2

I have the following function in a controller

```
public function actionSave_role() {

        $role = new Auth_Item;

        if ($role->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $role->save()) {
            //echo '<pre>'; print_r($role->getErrors());
            //yii\helpers\VarDumper::dump($role->getErrors(), 10, true);
            //pring_r($role->getErrors());
            //die();
            return $this->actionGet_role($role->id);
        }
}
```

The POST returns true, but no data is entered in the database. I'm trying to view the errors. There has to be some kind of validation not being met the the database but I haven't been able to figure it out. So I'm trying view the actual error, which has proven difficult, my attempts are all commented out. Still working on my PHP debugging skills. I believe that they are all 'failing' to print for the same reason, which has to do with where the data is actually being printed out.

Is there any way to kill the application right after $role->save() and view $role->getErrors()? Any other advice on debugging this issue would also be appreciated!

**Edit1:**

Tried

```
$role->save(false); //No Luck
```

Here is my record model

```
`auth_item`(`id`, `name`, `owner_user_id`, `type`, `description`, `rule_name`, `data`, `created_at`, `updated_at`, `admin`, `create_package`, `read_package`, `update_package`, `delete_package`)
```

This is my saveRole javascript function to kick things off:

```
function saveRole(role){
    var newRole = {
        _csrf: csrf,
        'Role[id]': role.id,
        'Role[name]': role.name,
        'Role[description]': role.description,
        'Role[admin]': role.admin ? role.admin = 1 : role.admin = 0,
        'Role[create_package]': role.create_package ? role.create_package = 1 : role.create_package = 0,
        'Role[read_package]': role.read_package ? role.read_package = 1 : role.read_package = 0,
        'Role[update_package]': role.update_package ? role.update_package = 1 : role.update_package = 0,
        'Role[delete_package]': role.delete_package ? role.delete_package = 1 : role.delete_package = 0
    };

    var request = $http({
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},
        url: 'roles/save_role', 
        method: "POST",
        data: $.param(newRole)
    });

    return request.then(handleSuccess, handleError);
};
```

This is my Auth_Item AcitveRecord model

```
class Auth_Item extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
{
public static function tableName()
{
    return 'auth_item';
}

public function rules()
{
    return [
        [['name'], 'required'],
        [['created_at', 'updated_at'], 'safe'],
        [['name'], 'string', 'max' => 255]
    ];
}

public function beforeSave($insert) {
    if ($insert) {
        $this->owner_user_id = Yii::$app->user->identity->id;
        $this->rule_name = null;
        $this->type = 1;
        $this->data = null;
        $this->created_at = new \yii\db\Expression('NOW()');

    }
    $this->updated_at = new \yii\db\Expression('NOW()');
    return true;
}
}
```

Here is my table structure:

```
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `auth_item` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(64) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `owner_user_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `type` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `description` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
  `rule_name` varchar(64) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `data` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
  `created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `admin` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `create_package` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `read_package` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `update_package` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `delete_package` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `name` (`name`),
  KEY `rule_name` (`rule_name`),
  KEY `idx-auth_item-type` (`type`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=11 ;

ALTER TABLE `auth_item`
ADD CONSTRAINT `auth_item_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`rule_name`) REFERENCES `auth_rule` (`name`) ON DELETE SET NULL ON UPDATE CASCADE;
```

**Edit2:**

Here is where I'm at. I think its getting closer. Post is still returning 200 OK, data still not actually making it into the auth_item table.

```
public function actionSave_role() {
    $auth = Yii::$app->authManager;
    $id = $_POST["Role"]["id"];
        $roleModel = null;
        if ($id != null) {  // contact exists
            $roleModel = Auth_Item::findOne($id);
        } else {
            $roleModel = new Auth_Item();
        }

        if ($roleModel->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {
            $role = $auth->createRole($roleModel->name);
            $role->data = $roleModel->data;
            $role->description = $roleModel->description;
            $role->admin = $roleModel->admin;
            $role->create_package = $roleModel->create_package;
            $role->read_package = $roleModel->read_package;
            $role->update_package = $roleModel->update_package;
            $role->delete_package = $roleModel->delete_package;
            //End Posted data
            $role->rule_name = null;
            $role->type = 1;
            $role->created_at = new \yii\db\Expression('NOW()');
            //$role->updated_at = new \yii\db\Expression('NOW()');
            $role->owner_user_id = Yii::$app->user->identity->id;

            $auth->add($role);

            return $this->actionGet_role($role->id);
        }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

For authmanager is not save to use but you shuold create a role and the  add the role

**I use this actionCreate**

```
/**
 * Creates a new AuthItem model.
 * If creation is successful, the browser will be redirected to the 'view' page.
 * @return mixed
 */
public function actionCreate()
{
    $model = new AuthItem();
    $auth = Yii::$app->authManager;


    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {
        switch ($model->type) {
            case AuthItem::TYPE_ROLE :   // 1 = TYPE_ROLE
                $role = $auth->createRole($model->name);
                $role->data         = $model->data;
                //$role->ruleName     = $model->rule_name;
                $role->description  = $model->description;
                //$role->type         = $model->type;
                $auth->add($role);
                break;                    
             case AuthItem::TYPE_PERMISSION :  // 2 = TYPE_PERMISSION
                $permission  = $auth->createPermission($model->name);
                $permission->data         = $model->data;
                //$permission->ruleName     = $model->rule_name;
                $permission->description  = $model->description;
                //$permission->type         = $model->type;
                $auth->add($permission);
                break;              
            default:
                break;
        }
        return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->name]);
    } else {
        return $this->render('create', [
            'model' => $model,
        ]);
    }
}
```

**this the model**

```
<?php

    namespace vendor\dfenx\auth\models;

    use Yii;

    /**
     * This is the model class for table "auth_item".
     *
     * @property string $name
     * @property integer $type
     * @property string $description
     * @property string $rule_name
     * @property string $data
     * @property integer $created_at
     * @property integer $updated_at
     *
     * @property AuthAssignment[] $authAssignments
     * @property AuthRule $ruleName
     * @property AuthItemChild[] $authItemChildren
     */
    class AuthItem extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
    {

        const TYPE_ROLE       = '1';
        const TYPE_PERMISSION = '2';

        const TEXT_TYPE_ROLE       = 'TYPE_ROLE';
        const TEXT_TYPE_PERMISSION = 'TYPE_PERMISSION';
        const TEXT_ERROR_TYPE_NOT_ASSIGNED  = 'ERROR_TYPE_NOT_ASSIGNED';

        /**
         * @inheritdoc
         */
        public static function tableName()
        {
            return 'dfenx_auth_item';
        }

        /**
         * @inheritdoc
         */
        public function rules()
        {
            return [
                [['name', 'type'], 'required'],
                [['type', 'created_at', 'updated_at'], 'integer'],
                [['description', 'data'], 'string'],
                [['name', 'rule_name'], 'string', 'max' => 64]
            ];
        }

        /**
         * @inheritdoc
         */
        public function attributeLabels()
        {
            return [
                'name' => Yii::t('app', 'Name'),
                'type' => Yii::t('app', 'Type'),
                'description' => Yii::t('app', 'Description'),
                'rule_name' => Yii::t('app', 'Rule Name'),
                'data' => Yii::t('app', 'Data'),
                'created_at' => Yii::t('app', 'Created At'),
                'updated_at' => Yii::t('app', 'Updated At'),
            ];
        }

        /**
         * @return \yii\db\ActiveQuery
         */
        public function getAuthAssignments()
        {
            return $this->hasMany(AuthAssignment::className(), ['item_name' => 'name']);
        }

        /**
         * @return \yii\db\ActiveQuery
         */
        public function getRuleName()
        {
            return $this->hasOne(AuthRule::className(), ['name' => 'rule_name']);
        }

        /**
         * @return \yii\db\ActiveQuery
         */
        public function getAuthItemChildren()
        {
            return $this->hasMany(AuthItemChild::className(), ['child' => 'name']);
        }
    }
```

Comment: I actually tried that earlier,and again now. Still no data in the DB.

Comment: 'authManager' => [
            'class' => 'yii\rbac\DbManager',
            'defaultRoles' => ['guest']
        ],

Comment: Can I take a look at your AuthItem Model?

Comment: Added Edit2, attempted to implement a hybrid of our code. I should also note I have altered the auth_item table definition slightly to add an id PK in attempt to implement what I explained here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33104779/yii2-user-defined-roles-permissions-rbac-vs-other . This could possibly be the source of some issues...